# Do I need to call the functions in my smart contract?

Tags: solidity, remix, contract-invocation

Lets say I have a contract including the following:

```
uint256 public _burnFee = 3;

function setBurnFeePercent(uint256 burnFee) external onlyOwner {
        _burnFee = burnFee;
}
```

I compile and deploy this contract on remix and remix shows me all the functions on its interface.

Do i need to actually pass a value and call the function `setBurnFeePercent` or is it already running?

Answer (score 0):

Once a contract is deployed, it does not "run itself". Functions always need to be called if you want the contract to do anything. They can be called directly or by another contract.

- In your example, the `setBurnFeePercent` function takes one parameter, a
  `uint256`.
- The function can only be called externally (the    `external`
  keyword), which means that your contract cannot call it    from
  another function.
- It can only be called by the address set as owner of the contract (the modifier `onlyOwner`).
- Finally, once successfully called, it will replace the `_burnFee` value by the `uint256` passed as a parameter and save it on the blockchain until it is changed again through another function call.